# Error:The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I changed to  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" after that I got "The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString "  error

I installed 
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient,
 1. EntityFramework 6.0.0
 2. MySql.Data
 3. MySql.Data.Entities.EF6
But Still it's showing Error Here 
[image]

```
      <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <!--<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.EntityClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>-->
  <!--<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>-->
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Insert-20140428144514;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Insert-20140428144514.mdf" />
<add name="CollectionsalesEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.InsertModel.csdl|res://*/Models.InsertModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.InsertModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=;user id=;password=;database=&quot;" providerName="System.Data.MySqlClient" />
<add name="calculationEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.calculation.csdl|res://*/Models.calculation.ssdl|res://*/Models.calculation.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=;user id=;password=;database=&quot;" providerName="System.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

```
     <system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  <add name="EF Caching Data Provider" invariant="EFCachingProvider" description="Caching Provider Wrapper" type="EFCachingProvider.EFCachingProviderFactory, EFCachingProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=def642f226e0e59b" />
  <add name="EF Caching Data Provider for Web" invariant="EFCachingProvider.Web" description="Caching Provider Wrapper for Web" type="EFCachingProvider.Web.EFCachingProviderFactory, EFCachingProvider.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=def642f226e0e59b" />
  <add name="EF Generic Provider Wrapper" invariant="EFProviderWrapper" description="Generic Provider Wrapper" type="EFProviderWrapperToolkit.EFProviderWrapperFactory, EFProviderWrapperToolkit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=def642f226e0e59b" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Comment: @Gaz Winter samething as title